# Inheritance of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I'm new to iOS and I'm trying to understand how the platform works, so excuse me if I make any dumb questions.

My question is based on the problem present in this post:
[Inheritance on view controller Objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002714/inheritance-on-view-controller-objective-c)

So far, I understand I can inherit controllers, but can I inherit a view? I think the answer is NO. If that is the case, what is the best way to solve the following problem?

I have a card matching game.  Now, I have to expand the game to have a similar card game but with a different deck and rules.

Therefore, I want to reuse the code and have a main controller and 2 inherited controllers that redefine the creation of the deck.  Now I need to have 2 different views because the two games have a different number of cards.  So, what is the best way to do this?  Would I have to copy all the controls from one view to another and modify what's needed?

Comment: You apparently have some significant misconceptions.  UIView is a class.  UIViewController is a class.  UIButton is a class which is a subclass of UIControl which is a subclass of UIView.  Class inheritance defines the function of the class and what functions it has in common with other similar classes.  Inheritance does *not* define the way some views are placed in other views to build up a more complex view structure.

Comment: (A typical iPhone screen will have maybe 50 views on it.  Each label is a separate view, each image is a separate view, each button is a separate view, and there are "container" views which contain the other views.  Everything you see on the screen (and a lot you don't) is a view.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, not knowing the platform that well I wanted to make sure there is no mechanism to share some part of the view. So if I want to make a view that is similar to another one the only way is for me to copy that view to create a new one...is that correct?

Comment: The view is "owned" by the view controller.  If you want to "share" a view, use a common superclass view controller between your specialized view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit a view just fine.  Just create a subclass of `UIView` when you add a new file and then import that subclass.

Regarding your question, I feel like the best way to approach it would be to have a subclass of `UIViewController` called something like `CardsController` which has a deck property and can manage the display and change of cards based on a set of rules defined by you.  Then, subclass that view controller further for each of your two games, since they both make use of cards.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer...(please correct me if I am wrong) I have a view in my Main.storyboard and two different controllers for 2 different card card, one inherits the other...
the problem is that I have only one view and in the Custom Class right tab in Xcode I can only select a controller... is this right?
So are you suggesting that the view is only one but then i should control the visibility of the buttons/elements in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass any kind of object, controllers, views, whatever
ex:

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView

@end
```

If your two different views share a lot of code, then you shouldn't create them separately. They should have a common parent with the common methods and both of them inherit from this generic uiview

Comment: Ok maybe I got this wrong and now getting confused but isn't the code in the controller and not the view? doesn't the view have only the layout objects? I have a main controller that has all the code and then i created a new controller that inherits from the main controller and overrides some abstract methods...now i don't understand what is the next step to have a different view to my inherited controller...

Comment: When you create a `UIViewController` it has a view with it but you can add Subviews to it or modify it in any way you want.
You can create a new class, that inherits from `UIView` and add this new view as subview of the main `UIViewController` view